# Does casting to char* and then casting back to original type break strict aliasing?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, strict-aliasing

For example, I cast a pointer to an `int` to a pointer to `char`:

```
int originalVar = 1;
char *arr = (char *)&originalVar;
```

Then I cast it back (maybe I pass `arr` to another function):

```
int *pOriginal = (int *)arr;
```

Does it break the rules? Or any undefined behaviors here?

--

Actually my doubts are about understanding the "effective type" in C standard

Does the object pointed by `arr` always regard `int` as its effective type?

(Even if `arr` is passed to another function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works and is well defined because the alignment of the original pointer will match the int.

Only issue casing a char* to an int* can be alignment requirements. Certain architectures require an int to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary (ie. the last two binary digits of the pointer are 0). A char* generally does not have that limitation.

However, since it started as an int*, and int* -> char* is never an issue, this will not cause any issue.

Comment: "_Only_ issue cas(t)ing a char* to an int* can be alignment requirements"?  I did not know C specified that alignment could be the only issue.

Comment: more complications with function pointers and class pointers, but built-in types you only worry about alignment.

Comment: Is the idea that one only worries about alignment the result of your experience or is that a specification?   I thought C allowed different types to exist in separate address spaces and that non-alignment issue came into play in casting.   Not familiar with "class pointers" in C.  Can you provide a C class pointer example?