# Does casting to a char pointer to increment a pointer by a certain amount and then accessing as a different type violate strict aliasing?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

For example, you might want to align a `void *` that is aligned to 4-byte boundary to 16-byte boundary.

```
int *align16(void *p) {
    return (int *)((char *)p + 16 - (uintptr_t)p % 16);
}
```

Normally, accessing an `int *` casted from a `char *` violates strict aliasing rules and invokes undefined behaviour, while the opposite is safe.

Is it still undefined behaviour in cases such as above?

I found [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981787/does-casting-to-char-and-then-casting-back-to-original-type-break-strict-aliasi) similar to this where the reply says it's fine as far as the alignment is kept. However, that answer does not mention anything about strict aliasing and did not reply to a comment related to the standard specification.

---

A side question. The optimized compiler output of `align16` can be decompiled as follows.

```
int *align16(void *p) {
    return (int *)((uintptr_t)p + 16 & -16);
}
```

How does the standard deal with such case, accessing a pointer modified while casted to a `uintptr_t`?

Comment: Strict aliasing is about accessing the same memory by dereferencing pointers to different types.  Here, the `char *` expression is never dereferenced; in fact nothing is dereferenced at all.  So strict aliasing is irrelevant to the `align16` function itself, though conceivably it could be relevant to whatever the caller is doing.

Comment: But generally, yes, this kind of arithmetic is safe.  For instance, you couldn't implement `qsort` without it.

Comment: Note, though, [C11, **6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): " A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."  If you produce a misaligned pointer for a particular type, you do not need to dereference the pointer to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: However, as to converting the pointer to `uintptr_t` and doing arithmetic, the C standard says nothing more than "implementation-defined" (6.3.2.3 p5-6).  Nevertheless, `(uintptr_t)p % 16` certainly results in some integer between 0 and 15, and so provided that it comes out to be a multiple of the size of `int`, this code will return a pointer to some element of the array passed to it.

Comment: Unrelated, `align16` will *always* bump the pointer, even if the pointer is *already* aligned on a 16-character paragraph boundary. I sincerely doubt that was intended or desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does casting to a char pointer to increment a pointer by a certain amount and then accessing as a different type violate strict aliasing?

Not inherently so.

> Normally, accessing an `int *` casted from a `char *` violates strict aliasing rules

Not necessarily.  Strict aliasing is about the (effective) type of the pointed-to object.  It is quite possible for the object to which a `char *` points to be an `int`, or compatible with `int`, or to be *assigned* effective type `int` as a consequence of the (write) access.  In such cases, casting to `int *` and dereferencing the result is perfectly valid.

There are, yes, lots of cases in which casting a `char *` to an `int *` and then dereferencing the result would constitute a strict-aliasing violation, but it is not specifically because of the involvement of, or the casting to or from, type `char *`.

The above applies regardless of how the particular `char *` value was obtained, so in your particular example case, too.  If the result of your pointer computation is a valid pointer, and the object to which it points is genuinely an (effective) `int` or is compatible with `int` in one of the specific ways documented in section 6.5 of the language spec, then reading the pointed-to value via the pointer is fine.  Otherwise, it is a strict-aliasing violation.

Attempting to dereference a pointer value that is not correctly aligned for its type is a potential issue in general with pointer manipulation, but the strict aliasing rule is stronger than and effectively inclusive of pointer alignment considerations.  If you have an access that satisfies the strict aliasing rule then the pointer involved must be satisfactorily aligned for its type.  The reverse is not necessarily true.

---

Do note, however, that although on many platforms, your `align16()` will indeed attempt to perform a read of a 16-byte-aligned object, the C language specifications do not require that to be so.  Pointer-to-integer and integer-to-pointer conversions are explicitly allowed, but their results are *implementation defined*.  It is not necessarily the case that value on the integer side of such a conversion reports on or controls the alignment of the pointer on the other side.

> How does the standard deal with such case, accessing a pointer modified while casted to a uintptr_t?

See above.  Pointer-to-integer and integer-to-pointer conversions have implementation-defined effect as far as the language spec is concerned.  However, on most implementations you're likely to meet, your two versions of `align16()` will have equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Operations which displace a structure pointer by an amount which is not a multiple of the structure's size and then make use of the resulting pointer had unambiguously defined semantics in the language defined by the 1974 C Reference Manual.  The language would be useless for many purposes if such operations could not be expected to behave usefully in at least some cases, but some existing implementations do not process them meaningfully in all cases, and nothing in any formal description of the language indicates when such operations should or should not be expected to behave meaningfully (in a fashion analogous to the 1974 language).  The Standard does allow implementations to impose certain constraints, and deviate from the 1974 behavior if they are violated, but none seem applicable here.

Given a function like

```
struct foo { int x,y; };
int test(struct foo *p1, struct foo *p2)
{
    p1->x = 1;
    p2->y = 2;
    return p1->x;
}
```

no constraint would be violated if p1->x and p2->y happened to coincide, but neither clang nor gcc would produce code that would return 2 in that case.  Even if the code were something like:

```
struct foo { int x,y; };
void test(struct foo *p1, struct foo *p2, int mode)
{
  p1->x = 1;
  p2->y = 2;
  if (mode)
    p1->x = 1;
}
```

whose behavior should be defined if calling code access the storage exclusively via p2->y in cases where mode is zero, and exclusively via p1->x otherwise, clang would generate code that would the shared storage location holding 2 even when mode is zero.

If actions which derive a pointer of one type from an object of another, manipulate it in "weird" ways, and then access the resulting pointer were regarded as unsequenced with regard to intervening actions that access the storage via other means, then the above constructs would both invoke Undefined Behavior in the storage-overlap case because they involve unsequenced accesses to partially-overlapping objects of type `struct foo`.  Unfortunately, even though such a rule would allow nearly all of the useful type-based aliasing optimizations without interfering with useful type-punning constructs, and even though compilers don't behave reliably in cases that would violate such a rule, the way the Standard is worded uses a different abstraction model which fits neither programmer needs nor the behavior of actual compilers.

Comment: It's not easy for me to understand your answer. Do you mean that `foo::x` and `foo::y` overlapping is valid C (I know `::` is not C but..)? Doesn't the standard allow non-accessible padding between `x` and `y`?

Comment: @xiver77: In general, the notion of "address" implies that performing an operation on a non-register-qualified non-bitfield lvalue is equivalent to taking the address of that lvalue, and performing the operation on the associated pointer.  The Standard recognizes a few specific cases where a pointer that is usable to access a region of storage might compare equal to one that isn't, but if two pointers would each be usable to access a region of storage, they may be used to access it interchangeably.  If `p1` and `p2` are constructed such that `&p1->x` and `&p2->y` would be the same...

Comment: ...and either would, individually, be able to access the storage in question, the Standard does not specify any way in which use of one to access the storage would preclude use of the other to access that same storage.  The Standard probably *should* specify some limitations, but it would be necessary to abandon the "Effective Type" abstraction model around which clang and gcc were designed, in favor of one which would be nicer for programmers and compiler writers alike, but which clang and gcc would have to be redesigned to support.

Comment: @xiver77: The main reason compilers would care about whether two lvalues might identify the same storage is so that they can know whether operations on them may be reordered so as to allow consolidation with other operations, a question which should be answerable by seeing whether there is anything visible nearby to suggest that such reordering would be problematic.  Clang and gcc, however, regard the ability of things to alias as a static trait which is unaffected by sequencing.

Comment: @xiver77: I added a new paragraph at the start; does that help offer some perspective?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and think about some interesting aspects of the language I haven't thought about before.